# Manipulating string with Postgres

Tags: string, postgresql

I need to extract the product and product version from event table, that would be emas product and version 3.2.5.

Thats event table looks like:
[image]

With the query

```
select creacion,descripcion 
from event 
where descripcion ~ 'desarollo john';
```

I have the following result:

```
  creacion                |   description
1  2020-09-1 10:08:34     |   desarollo john 1.8.3
2  2020-09-1 10:08:36     |   desarollo maria 1.7.3
3  2020-09-1 10:08:38     |   desarollo helena 1.9.3
4  2020-09-1 10:08:40     |   desarollo pedro 1.3.3
5  2020-09-1 10:08:42     |   desarollo ana 1.0.3
```

But I want to receive the result as follows:

```
product=john version=1.8.3
```

I tried some queries like:

```
select creacion,descripcion 
from evento 
where descripcion ~ 'desarollo john 1.8.3' select substring ('desarollo john 1.8.3',10);

select creacion,descripcion 
from evento 
where descripcion ~ substring ('desarollo john 1.8.3',10);

select substring('desarollo john') as producto select substring('R-' ) as versión, creacion,descripcion  where descripción like 'desarollo john%';
```

But I didn't get anywhere near what I need.

How should I make this query and manipulate the result?

Comment: I have edited and uploaded an image of the output

Comment: "_But I didn't get anywhere near what I need._" What **do** you get? Why is that wrong?

Comment: The first two querys I tried don't change the final result, the output is still the same as the picture. And the second gives error SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «select»
  Position: 49

Comment: @AkhileshMishra The last name is always the product and the last 3 numbers (after the R) is the version

Comment: but in you example R is not always there sometime times it is missing or `R-` or  'R.`. even sometimes there is no space between product and version.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra Yes, you're right. But do you have any idea how I should start? Somehow, if there is R that removes it and gives me back just the numbers. If there is no R, just give me the numbers back.

Comment: @ElizamaMelo I have updated the answer which will give you correct version. It will miss only one scenario where you don't have space between product and version

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very clear but it seems you want to extract the version and product from `description` and represent in a column format.
try this:

```
select 
split_part(split_part(descripcion,'Development step to test ',2),' ',1) "product",
substring(descripcion from '\d+.\d+.\d+') "version"
from event where descripcion ~ 'Development step to test ';
```

Comment: I need to extract from this result the product and the version, which in this case would be "emas" and "3.2.5". And format it to be like 'product=emas version=3.0.5'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I used to solve this problem. I hope to help someone!

select upper(substring(substring(descripcion,27),0,length(substring(descripcion,27))-position(' ' in reverse(substring(descripcion,27)))+1))  as "producto", replace(replace(replace(reverse(substring(reverse(descripcion),0,position(' ' in reverse(descripcion)))), 'R-',''), 'R.',''),'R','') as "version", creacion
from evento where descripcion ~ 'Paso de desarrollo a test ';